# Why my .bashrc has error?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, bash, paths, hadoop

I added this path to .bashrc file .

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export $PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export $PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
```

but when I apply command `source .bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`  Ubuntu show me this message:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and want to install hadoop-2.7.2.

Comment: For future reference, the error "not a valid identifier" means that the shell can't accept the name you're calling something. For example, `function $ { true; }` output: `bash: \`$': not a valid identifier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can see your lines are correct except two:

```
export $PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export $PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
```

should be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
```

Comment: i already do that but still has the same problem ,,!

Comment: Then one or more of your paths you entered may contain an error. Re-check them. According to your question this is the valid answer.